# Server-side button works in Firefox but not IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Anyone know why a simple onclick="btnSubmit_Click" button that calls a server-side function would work in Firefox but not IE.

Comment: Ricky, your question is too vague, can you include details of how you have coded this, what you have tried, etc?

Comment: It's a safe bet that ASP.NET was tested against IE, so it's not going to be as simple as browser compatibility. The question, as Roberto points out, is how you set this up.

Comment: The C# .Net code does a Response.Redirect("www.website.com"). This works in Firefox and Chrome but not IE. I understand that client side and server side are two completely different processes which is why this is throwing me for a loop. Maybe a server setting I have to adjust.

Answer (score 0):

Server side code is irrespective of the browser.Hope some problem with your code only.Check it

Comment: See my comment above. I'm clueless as to why this would fire depending on the browser I'm thinking it's a server setting.

Comment: Not sure, but it sounds as if they're saying the button is not triggering the server-side code.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying. But only in IE what could possibly be the basis for this. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Ricky. Keep it simple. Create a new ASP.NET Web app with a simple form, add a button which fires an OnClick to it. Im pretty sure that will work in IE, which implies its not IE the problem, but how you've implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

It's the default button behavior. In all browsers I've tested *except* Internet Explorer, a button without a type attribute saying otherwise has a default submit behavior. In IE, it's just a button (`type="button"`), running local code, by default; you need to add a `type="submit"` attribute to cause the form to be submitted to the server for processing if the called local code doesn't submit it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the details of your implementation, I suggest trying to use Internet Explorer's developer tool, to see what is being posted, if anything, when you click that button.

It may lead you to something else that could help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. Apparently IE Compatibility Mode has something to do with it. I got my program to work by disabling it on my Master page from an [article](http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2010/03/css-ie8-meta-tag-to-disable.html) I found.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE10; IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
         <title></title>
```